# SAML 2.0 Support for Java Jersey Web/REST application

Tags: java, spring, jersey, saml, okta

We have a existing java web based application built on Jersey framework and looking to provide SSO support using Okta or any other IDP. I have seen many example applications for saml support for spring based applications. Is there any framework which can provide saml support for Jersey based applications? Or Spring SAML extensions can be tweaked to provide support for non-spring baed applications?

Please provide any links or pointers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you can roll your own by creating a `ContainerRequestFilter`.. I think you need your Jersey clients to be able to follow redirects (to the IdP and back) etc. Is that possible in your environment?

Comment: I think it should be possible. But, do you have any sample applications/library creating filter and managing redirects and call backs?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to apply the [Spring Security SAML](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/) extension on a non-*Spring* application. We are using *Spring SAML* with a *Wicket* web application.

I built a prototype with *ADFS* as an IdP to check feasibility, before we implemented this approach on the project. You can find the prototype in my Bitbucket repository: [blog-spring-security](https://bitbucket.org/sw-samuraj/blog-spring-security).

Basically, you can use `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` which should transparently enable *Spring Security* in your application.

```java
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public WebAppInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfiguration.class);
    }
}
```

Spring configuration for SAML is quite extensive (couple of pages of source code), so I won't paste it here, but if you are going to use Java configuration you can utilize my [SecurityConfiguration.java](https://bitbucket.org/sw-samuraj/blog-spring-security/src/tip/src/main/java/cz/swsamuraj/wicketspring/security/SecurityConfiguration.java).

In case of XML configuration, I would recommend to follow either [Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/), or sample project [securityContext.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/blob/master/sample/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/securityContext.xml).

Comment: Nice! Thanks for sharing. We implemented our own SAML implementation for our Wicket application, based on OpenSAML, and found most of the time went to configuring all the SAML properties (keys, certificate, attributes to map etc.)